# Application crashes in iOS 7 when place holder text is added to text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, autolayout

My application crashes in ios7 when i add a placeholder to text field ,the same works fine in ios8. Added controls programmatically with auto layout

As suggested i added `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` at the end of `viewDidLayout` delegate method but still the app crashed with the below exception

> Assertion failure Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITextField's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

Comment: can you please upload some code? and did you used autolayout?

Comment: yes add controls programmatically with auto layout constraints

Comment: @puneetha don't use layoutSubViews

Comment: inside autolayoutsubview call [ super layoutSubview] also.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important where you add your constraints programmatically. You should not add them in one of the layouting methods callbacks (like `layoutSubviews` or `viewdidLayoutSubviews`). That is because the system is expected to have the views layout after these methods are called and if you add new constraints after the views were already layouted and a new layout cycle is needed, there will be a crash.

I suggest you think about another method where you could add the new constraints. If there is no other place that would work for you, try adding the constraints before you call the `super` method, not the other way around.

So something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
      // Add constraints

      [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

If you could post some of your code, I would me more than happy to help you further :)